# Automatically materialize view from query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to automatically materialize a view based on a BigQuery query (all source tables are in BigQuery as well). Is there a lightweight solution for this in google cloud?

Comment: Do you mean you want to query a view (which is just some SQL under the hood) and have the results of that query written/materialised to a table?

Comment: I want to query a table, and produce another table from that query (on a regular interval).

Comment: So schedule a BigQuery job. Got it. See here: https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/21/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-this-time-using-cloud-storage-cloud-functions/

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery doesn't support materialized views, here is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72224267) and 
 [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996) another one (that you can star to increase visibility)

You can create something from scratch executing a CRON at regular interval that will run a query job with output table as the one you want to produce.

Like with gcloud

```
bq query --destination_table project.dataset.materialized_view --use_legacy_sql=false --replace "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.view_name`"
```

Or with the [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results) as well

Comment: Materialized views are available as of Feb 25, 2021: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/bigquery-materialized-views-now-ga